# How can I load .wasm files stored in a subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I am trying out a simple example to call a C function compiled to .wasm with JavaScript.

This is the `counter.c` file:

```
#include <emscripten.h>

int counter = 100;

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int count() {  
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
}
```

I compiled it using `emcc counter.c -s WASM=1 -o counter.js`.

My `main.js` JavaScript file:

```
Module['onRuntimeInitialized'] = onRuntimeInitialized;
const count = Module.cwrap('count ', 'number');

function onRuntimeInitialized() {
    console.log(count());
}
```

My `index.html` file only loads both .js files in the body, nothing else:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="counter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

It works fine / prints 101 to the console, **but when I move the `counter.c` file to a `wasm` subdirectory**, recompile it with emscripten and update the `script` tag to `src="wasm/counter.js"`, the `counter.js` script tries to load `counter.wasm` from the root directory instead of the `wasm` subdirectory and I get the error:

`counter.js:190 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: failed to load wasm binary file at 'counter.wasm'`

I did some research, but I didn't find any way to tell emscripten to let the generated .js file load the .wasm from the same subdirectory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the generated 'loader' file that emscripten creates, it has an `integrateWasmJS` function as follows:

```
function integrateWasmJS(Module) {
  var method = Module['wasmJSMethod'] || 'native-wasm';
  Module['wasmJSMethod'] = method;

  var wasmTextFile = Module['wasmTextFile'] || 'hello.wast';
  var wasmBinaryFile = Module['wasmBinaryFile'] || 'hello.wasm';
  var asmjsCodeFile = Module['asmjsCodeFile'] || 'hello.temp.asm.js';

  ...
}
```

You can see that the `wasmBinaryFile` indicates the location of the binary. If it is not set it provides a default.

It looks like you should be able to override this in your `main.js` file as follows:

```
Module['wasmBinaryFile'] = 'wasm/counter.wasm';
```

Answer (score 12):

As explained by [ColinE in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46340091/4289700), you should look at the integrateWasmJS() function generated by the emcc compiler (counter.js). The body of that function has changed recently and now it looks like this:

```
function integrateWasmJS() {
    ...
    var wasmBinaryFile = 'counter.wasm';

    if (typeof Module['locateFile'] === 'function') {
        ...
        if (!isDataURI(wasmBinaryFile)) {
          wasmBinaryFile = Module['locateFile'](wasmBinaryFile);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

If this is the case, then you should add a "locateFile" function to the global Module variable. So in your HTML, you could add the following snippet before importing the counter.js file:

```
<script>
  var Module = {
    locateFile: function(s) {
      return 'wasm/' + s;
    }
  };
</script>
```